# How to show a combined image of two resource png images in android

Tags: android, android-image

My application shows a gridview list with some devices.  Each devices has four states.  I have a different types of devices images and four state images.  I want to combine device images with state image and display in gridview.  The images are stores in application resource.  Images are shown using ImageView.

How i can do this  ?

image1

[image]

image2

[image]

the output will be

[image]

**edited**
new images

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by combine? Do you want them to display one on top of the other? Side by side? Have you used a custom layout for your grid items? Provide some code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: post the images you want to combine and image that you want to produce using two images.

Comment: You could try using two ImageViews occupying the same layout space? In order for the images to combine, the backgrounds of the images would need to be transparent.

Comment: @SweetWisher frame layout ?

Comment: Yes u can design such image using over lapping with frame layout

Comment: I am not aware on using frame layout... i using this image on customized gridview

Comment: wait.. m giving you code

Comment: very nice who is -ve voted.  please explain why... it will be better

Comment: need your original box images like give first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this works great with me

```
public Bitmap combineImages(int boxDrawableId , int closeDrawableId) {

        Bitmap box = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),boxDrawableId);
        Bitmap close = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), closeDrawableId);

        Bitmap bitmapCreate = Bitmap.createBitmap(box.getWidth(), box.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bitmapCreate);

        comboImage.drawBitmap(box, 0, 0, null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(close, box.getWidth()-close.getWidth(), box.getHeight()-close.getHeight(), null);
        if (box != null) {
            try {
                box.recycle();
                close.recycle();
                box = null;
                close = null;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
        }
        return bitmapCreate;
    }
```

**How to call?**

```
imgView.setImageBitmap(combineImages(R.drawable.box,R.drawable.close));
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes it is working... thanks... But it not show well in other images... see edited question.... Is it any dependency in background color

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Frame Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Remove" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The output of this code is : 
[image]

Comment: He wants to do it at dynamic way as per device not using xml.

Comment: Your solution is great, In this case i need dynamic way as said by Biraj Zalavadia.  +1 for you.  any way thanks